# "Recommend Deletion" should include a "Your answer has no examples" / "Your answer is not substantial enough" option

Tags: feature-request

Many of the low-quality posts tend to surface as there aren't sufficient information in there (like elaboration, examples, anecdotes, sample situations, etc).

Since IPS is moving towards having anecdotes and experiences in all of the answers here, I feel it is a good idea for the "Recommend Deletion" button for the review queues to have an option which says **"Your answer is not sufficient enough. Please add more information or personal experiences in your answer to support your points."** or something along those lines.

Also, would it be a good idea for the system to auto-generate the comment to the answer so that the user can improve on their answer? I've seen several occasions where more experienced users on this forum has had to type out the comment, such as in [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/16441/how-to-convince-my-wife-that-my-best-friend-and-i-are-just-friends/16478#16478) here, though there are many other instances where I see such comments. Maybe an auto-generated comment once the "Recommend Deletion" button has been pressed would be great for this purpose?

P.S. this is my first post on meta, please guide me along if I have mistaken the use of the meta.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the popup that shows *after* you've hit recommend deletion? The one that gives options such as 'comment on another post' 'thank you comment' 'I'm having this problem too comment'?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell yes, I am!

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of adding unsubstantial answers to the list of comments available as part of the VLQ queue but we'd need to put some thought into how the comment is worded.

Having a default comment as part of the VLQ queue would be very helpful in signaling to people new to the review queue that "do this" or other insubstantial answers aren't acceptable on this site, without them needing to dig through meta first. While it would be great if everyone sought out the rules and followed them, if that was the case we wouldn't need mods and a VLQ queue in the first place. Having additional signals about expected behavior makes it easier for people to develop a rudimentary understanding of site policy.

One thing to keep in mind with the comments that I'm leaving when working my way through the VLQ queue is that while the problem is generally the same *We expect questions to be more substantial* the suggested recourse needs to be tailored to each specific answer. While we could probably generate a generic enough recourse that it would technically be accurate in most situations it wouldn't do much to guide new users to how to fix their answer.

Comment: well yes, in your last paragraph you mentioned "it doesnt guide new users on how to fix their answer" it seems to me that the generic statement for the *vote to close for "what should I do?"* questions doesn't have a "personal touch" to it as well... and many new users (and even some experienced users) have some problems grasping the concept.. perhaps that logic can be applied here as well? Meaning to say that the statement can be a generic one but still allows OP or answerers alike to understand the general concept.

Comment: @enlighten_me On their own no canned comment will ever have a personal touch.

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment to get to my point. Accidentally pressed on the "enter" key